# What exactly defines a database as a "SQL database"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

From what I understand, Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, etc., are all "SQL databases", their syntax is about 90% similar, and their underlying implementation is different. I'm curious what exactly defines a SQL database.

Is there a SQL language standard that "SQL databases" extend? Or was SQL originally defined as "the language that Microsoft SQL Server reads" and then engines that read variations of the language became known as "SQL databases"?

Comment: May be of value to know about the concept of Relational Database, see for example:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming. There's no code, and no evidence of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL

> SQL became a standard of the American National Standards Institute
>   (ANSI) in 1986, and of the International Organization for
>   Standardization (ISO) in 1987.

And a bit more from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9075

> ```
> SQL:1999 is the ISO/IEC 9075:1999 standard of 1999.
> SQL:2003 is the ISO/IEC 9075:2003 standard of 2003.
> SQL:2006 is the ISO/IEC 9075:2006 standard of 2006.
> SQL:2008 is the ISO/IEC 9075:2008 standard of 2008.
> SQL:2011 is the ISO/IEC 9075:2011 standard of 2011.
> ```

So the answer is Yes. The SQL language has a couple of standards.

The history is a bit more complex. It started with this step:

> SQL was initially developed at IBM by Donald D. Chamberlin and Raymond F. Boyce in the early 1970s.

(From: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#History)